# condition within return statement

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function which takes as an argument a string and returns the same string but alternating upper and lower cases letters within the string. I know a longer solution to this, but I came up with the solution below which however is not working, and I am wondering why this does not work.

```
def myfunc(*args):
    return [b.lower() if a%2 else b.upper() for a,b in enumerate(args)]
```

The above piece of code gives me as output a full uppercase string, for example:

```
>>> myfunc('Hello')
['HELLO']
```

Comment: Please provide what you feed to that function and what you expect in return.

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't define the function using `def myfunc(args):` rather than `def myfunc(*args):`?

Comment: You are discovering one of the difficulties for novices with list comprehensions - you can’t debug inside the comprehension. Until you know what you’re doing you should simply write a for loop and add things to the list then return it - then you’ll be able to debug your own code or add print statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, first of all you function is not taking a single string now, but it can take several variables (because of the `*` you put in front of args), hence when you pass it the argument `"Hello"`, it actually gets a tuple object like `('Hello', )`. So in your for loop you actually iterate over that tuple instead of iterating over the characters of the string.

If you want to get a string, just remove the `*`.

```
def myfunc(args):
    return "".join([b.lower() if a%2 else b.upper() for a,b in enumerate(args)])
```

Note that you operation returns not a string but a list of characters. The `"".join([])` will concatenate the characters inside of your list into a string, separated by `""` (i.e nothing)

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 1):

You need to unpack the args (`*args`), but then this will return a list, so you need to join the string again too.

```
return "".join([b.lower() if a%2 else b.upper() for a,b in enumerate(*args)])
```

As noted in the comments, this only works if there is only one argument, if there isn't you may want to join the strings together, one such way is using chain, and then pass this in to enumerate instead

```
from itertools import chain
if len(args) > 1:
    single_arg = chain.from_iterable(args)
```

```
return "".join(b.lower() if a%2 else b.upper() for a,b in enumerate(chain.from_iterable(single_arg)))
```

Comment: `enumerate` won't accept `*args`, I think. It may work "by accident" if `args` contains only one item.

Comment: using a list comprehension with join is actually faster than passing a generator. and join creates a list anyway.

Comment: @mkrieger1 - Thanks for that! I'd only tested with the op's input but you make a good point